# Too many MethodWrapperImpl created in jersey application

Tags: jersey-2.0, hk2

Recently my jersey application got high GC problems.

By inspecting the heap dump, I found that there're a lot of MethodWrapperImpl as well as LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture became unreachable objects.
(About 19700 MethodWrapperImpl alive and around 40k+ MethodWrapperImpl in unreacheable objects).

My question is:

Is it a normal behavior? 
After all, I have only 1 resource and 1 resource method.

The heap dump shows that:

Total 32 instance of ClassReflectionHelperImpl and total 128 LRUHybridCache.

Btw, I'm using spring boot 2.0.5 and the jersey is on 2.26. (hk2 is 2.5.0-b42)
And it's hard to reproduce in local, only happens on production boxes with real traffic.

Leon

Comment: It doesn't seem correct.  There were some improvements in that area (the caching) in later releases of hk2, but without knowing your exact problem I'm not sure they will be fixed

Comment: I'm not sure why so many instances of ClassReflectionHelperImpl, maybe 1 instance per container? In my previous production release, I saw this number is 4.